# Android client library version for soclet.io 0.9.16

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I created an android application with latest socket io android [client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) and socket io 1.4.6 which works perfectly.

But now I want to use a socket io server vers 0.9.16 for some reasons. But the latest client library doesn't support it. Which is the matched version of the android client library(any) for socket io@0/9.16

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me how you managed to do that? I want to do the same in my Android Project. Currently, I'm using this...
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

Comment: Please refer this repo https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client. Connection to socket.io is successfully established by this using the repo. Tell me if you need any more explanations.